# vsftpd - Cannot upload file. Get err: 553

Tags: vsftpd

I installed VSFTPD on Centos7 and tried to set up FTP.
The vsftpd.conf file information is as follows:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
allow_ftpd_full_access
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
local_root=/home/share
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
pasv_address=ip
pasv_min_port=3000
pasv_max_port=3100
guest_enable=NO
```

I looked at a lot of posts and most of the answers I got were permissions and SELinux.
The dir `/home/share` 777 permission has been set.

[SELinux is enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jySU.png)

Would you please help me find out what the problem is? I would be very grateful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problems are that `allow_ftpd_full_access` is not a `vsftpd.conf` option, and that the `/home/share` directory has the wrong owner (see Steps 5 and 6).

Try this out...

> **NOTE** - Tested using two CentOS 7.9 virtual machines, on an Internal network, with IP addresses of 192.168.0.10 (client) and 192.168.0.11 (server), using your `vsftpd.conf` settings.

1. On the client, ensure the FTP client is installed: `sudo yum install ftp`
2. On the server, ensure the FTP daemon is installed: `sudo yum install vsftpd`
3. Temporarily open the firewall for FTP traffic on both machines, so you do not receive a `No route to host` error:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=20/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=21/tcp
```

4. On the server, allow FTP daemon traffic through the firewall: `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=ftp`
5. On the server, in your `vsftpd.conf` file, remove `allow_ftpd_full_access`. Instead, enter `sudo setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access=1` in the Terminal.
6. On the server, change the ownership of the `/home/share` folder from `root:root` to the FTP server's user name and group. In my case it was `ftp_server:ftp_server` group:

```
sudo chown ftp_server:ftp_server /home/share
```

7. On the server, start the FTP service: `sudo systemctl start vsftpd`
8. On the server, create a test file in the `/home/share` directory. You can change the ownership of the file, if you like, but I was able to `get` the file even if it was `root:root`:

```
echo "This file is from the FTP server." | sudo tee /home/share/ftp_server_file
```

9. On the client, create a test file in the client `home` directory: `echo "This file is from the FTP client." > ~/ftp_client_file`
10. On the client:

    - Open the FTP client
    - Get the server's `/home/share` directory listing
    - Get the server file
    - Put the client file

```
[ftp_client@localhost ~]$ ftp 192.168.0.11
Connected to 192.168.0.11 (192.168.0.11).
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (192.168.0.11:ftp_client): ftp_server
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,11,12,27).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
-rw-r--r--    1 0        0              34 Jan 16 21:06 ftp_server_file
226 Directory send OK.
ftp> get ftp_server_file
local: ftp_server_file remote: ftp_server_file
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,11,11,211).
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for ftp_server_file (34 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
34 bytes received in 4.5e-05 secs (755.56 Kbytes/sec)
ftp> put ftp_client_file
local: ftp_client_file remote: ftp_client_file
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,11,11,212).
150 Ok to send data.
226 Transfer complete.
34 bytes sent in 7.7e-05 secs (441.56 Kbytes/sec)
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,11,11,222).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000           34 Jan 16 21:18 ftp_client_file
-rw-r--r--    1 0        0              34 Jan 16 21:06 ftp_server_file
226 Directory send OK.
ftp> quit
221 Goodbye.
[ftp_client@localhost ~]$
```

11. Verify the files are both on the client and the server:

```
$ ll ftp*
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 ftp_server ftp_server 34 Jan 16 15:04 ftp_client_file
-rw-r--r--. 1 root       root       34 Jan 16 15:03 ftp_server_file
```

The initial permissions for both files were 644, but I had no problems.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your attention. I rebuilt VSFTPD on the other two servers according to the steps you said, and successfully put.I compared it and found out：My FTP root directory is ```/home/share```. I created an ```upload``` directory in this layer and set ```757``` permissions to it, and then work. Thank you very much！

Comment: YW @l-jackie, but please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work